# Weird unset() issue with session variable

Tags: php, session

I have a function which gets a session variable by a key and then reassigns it to a variable. I unset the session variable and return the variable I set. For some reason it is returning ''. If I remove the unset it works.

This returns null

```
if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $session_variable = $_SESSION[$key];
            var_dump($session_variable);
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            var_dump($session_variable);
            return $session_variable;
        }
    return '';
```

This returns the correct output when unset is omitted

```
if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $session_variable = $_SESSION[$key];
            var_dump($session_variable);
//          unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            var_dump($session_variable);
            return $session_variable;
        }
        return '';
```

I don't understand why unset is removing the variable $session_variable.

EDIT

The session variable previous is being set like this

```
$_SESSION['action'] = ['message' => 'bla', 'status' => 'success'];
```

The function is being called like this

```
(new Request)->getFlashedSessionVar('action'); //For testing
```

Comment: Your code is working fine without omitting unset session for me.

Comment: are you using any PHP framework or just native PHP?

Comment: I am using a inhouse legacy custom framework but most of it is raw PHP. I've searched for another unset function and one doesn't exist so I know it isn't being overwritten. I also have errors on so should be able to see if something is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the `$_SESSION[$key]` really is.
According to PHP documentation: `An exception to the usual assignment by value behaviour within PHP occurs with objects, which are assigned by reference in PHP 5. Objects may be explicitly copied via the clone keyword.`

This means you could just assign by reference and therefore endup unsetting the same object.

Please read here: [PHP Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: What is also odd is both var_dumps do not output anything when the unset is added. Even though the var_dump appears before the unset function. The $_SESSION[$key] is a standard assign e.g $_SESSION['action'] = [ 1 ,2]

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code in raw PHP. Its working fine for me

**Code**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $key = 'action';
    $_SESSION[$key] = [ 1 ,2] ;
    if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $session_variable = $_SESSION[$key];
            var_dump($session_variable);
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            var_dump($session_variable);
            return $session_variable;
        }
    return '';
?>
```

**Output**

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) } array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }
```

Comment: Thanks, Not sure what is causing this then. Will have to dive deeper. Thanks